# How to iterate through smaller chunks of data in API response

Tags: xml, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am running into a limitation with an API I am working with. At the moment the max rows it can return is 10000. The goal is to access a month worth of data which sometimes can be up 200000 rows. This API allows filtering by start_at_row and row_limit. It also returns row_count in the response. I will need to make multiple requests in order to capture all 200000 rows. I'm stuck on figuring out how to trigger the next request after the first 10000 rows and how to pick at exactly at 10001 and run the next 10000 rows. Is there a common method used for this problem? Any advice is welcome. Let me know which pieces of information from my code I can provide that can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Update, I was able to figure this out on my own after a little trial and error and more research on Google.

I added start_at_row and row_limit as global variables that equal to 1 and 2 respectively.

From there I added a while loop(start_at_row <= row_limit), I then captured the row_count from the response given by the API and made it equal to role_limit.

To break the loop I made and an if statement with start_at_row > row_limit